# Initial SwiftUI Animation inside ScrollView

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation

In my app I have a `ScrollView` that holds a `VStack`. The `VStack` has an `animation` modifier. It also has one conditional view with a `transition` modifier. The transition works. However, when the view first appears, the content scales up with a starting width of 0. You can see this on the green border in the video below. This only happens if the `VStack` is inside the `ScrollView` or the `VStack` has the `animation` modifier.

[image]

I have tried different other things like setting a `fixedSize` or setting `animation(nil)` but I cannot get it to work.

I don't care if there is an animation at the beginning or if the view transitions onto the screen. But I definitely do not want the bad animation at the beginning. When I click on the button, the `Text` and the `Button` should both animate.

I also tested this behaviour with the following simplified code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 32) {
                if self.viewModel.shouldShowText {
                    Text("Hello, World! This is a some text.")
                        .transition(
                            AnyTransition
                                .move(edge: .top)
                                .combined(
                                    with:
                                        .offset(
                                            .init(width: 0, height: -100)
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                }

                Button(
                    action: {
                        self.viewModel.didSelectButton()
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text("Button")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                    }
                )
            }
            .border(Color.green)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 5))
            .border(Color.red)

            HStack { Spacer() }
        }
        .border(Color.blue)
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private var number: Int = 0

    var shouldShowText: Bool {
        return self.number % 2 == 0
    }

    func didSelectButton() {
        self.number += 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine with Xcode 12 / iOS 14 (and stand-alone and in `NavigationView`), so I assume it is SwiftUI bug in previous versions.

Anyway, try to make animation be activated by value as shown below (tested & works)

```
  // ... other code
}
.border(Color.green)
.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 5), value: viewModel.number)   // << here !!
.border(Color.red)
```

and for this work it needs to make available published property for observation

```
class BlockViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var number: Int = 0             // << here !!
 
    // ... other code
```

Comment: Thank you :) I have never seen the `value:` option before. Using it, there is no animation at the beginning and the transition still works as expected. It even works with the `shouldShowText` property so I didn't have to change my `number` property.